# This app is not allowed to query for scheme error (have listed correct info.plist info)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to launch an ios app from my ios app made with flutter using the external_app_launcher and still getting this error (note I am using instagram since it is know, the app I am trying to launch is a different one but I am troubleshooting the functionality of why I am getting this error)  I have added the correct info to the info.plist it is below as well

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"
```

I have added the correct info to the .plist file and here is my code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Shade</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>shade</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and here is the code I am calling

```
void _launchApp() async {
  await LaunchApp.openApp(
    iosUrlScheme: 'instagram://',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/LSApplicationQueriesSchemes) is an array.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>scheme1</string>
    <string>scheme2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I figured this out, sometimes its the small things, when I added it from xcode it woudn't add it as an array I had to go back in and do it manually to fix the problem, thank you!